# Depth First Search labeling (Python)

Tags: python, networkx, depth-first-search

I need to label a tree's nodes by the order in which the nodes are visited during a depth first search. I have to implement it in Python. I'm trying to use [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/#) lib but still have no idea about how to do it. Do you guys have any idea about how to use it ? Or should I try to implement it by myself ?

Cheers, GP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not implement well know algorithms if they exist in the library. There you have a link to the doc of basic traversal algorithms.

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.traversal.html

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you create a new graph,

```
>>> import networkx as nx

>>> g = nx.DiGraph()
```

And you add some edges,

```
>>> g.add_edges_from([(0,1),(1,2),(0,3),(3,4),(3,5),(5,6)]) # etc
```

You can use `dfs_edges()` to traverse and to view the order of traversal.

```
>>> nodes = nx.dfs_edges(random_g, node_) # This creates an edges iterator
>>> nodes.next()
(0, 1)
>>> nodes.next()
(1, 2)
>>> nodes.next()
(0, 3)
>>>
```

And if you want you can grab the output from calls to `.next()`, to ascertain the nodes which are getting visited.

For example, (excluding the first node, 0),

```
>>> for n in nodes:
...     print n[1]
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
>>>
```